# How to call a C function from Fortran inside a DLL / XLL

Tags: c++, excel, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I would like to share how to call a C/C++ function in Fortran from a DLL/XLL. Actually I´m writing a Excel XLL Project to solve equations in Excel. My next steps are to implement Simplex, root finding and other functions from Fortran to be called in Excel by a XLL, not by DLL.

I´m using VS2015 to make the XLL (C++) and gfortran in Code::Blocks to compile the Fortran code.

You´ll need to use the following set of libraries from gfortran/Mingw to link the code in VS2015 C++: I used the files .a instead of .lib in VS2015, and it didn't cause problems::

```
libgcc.a, libgfortran.a, libmingwex.a,  libmsvcrt.a, libpthread.a,  libquadmath.a
```

C++ code:

```
prototypes:

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    extern "C" {
    #endif

    typedef void (*pF_arg2)(double, double &);

    double externo(pF_arg2 cfunk, double x);

    void dobraC(double x, double &y); // call-back function

    #ifdef __cplusplus
    }
    #endif 

    void dobraC(double x, double &y) // call-back function
    {

        y = x * 2;

    }


    __declspec(dllexport) double Dobra2x(double arg) // Fortran Interop
    {

        double x, y;

        try
        {       
            x = arg;        
            y = externo(&dobraC, x);        
        }
        catch (...)
        {
        }

        return y;
    }
```

Fortran/GFortran code is as follows:

```
real(c_double) FUNCTION externo(cfunk, x)  bind(c, name = "externo")
use iso_c_binding
implicit none


! Define interface of call-back routine.

    ABSTRACT INTERFACE    
    SUBROUTINE callback (x, y)

    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING    
    REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: x    
    REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE), INTENT(OUT) :: y        
    END SUBROUTINE callback    
    END INTERFACE   

    REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: x    
    REAL(KIND=C_DOUBLE) :: y    
    TYPE(C_FUNPTR), INTENT(IN), VALUE :: cfunk    
    PROCEDURE(callback), POINTER :: funk

    ! Convert C to Fortran procedure pointer.    
    CALL C_F_PROCPOINTER (cfunk, funk)        
    ! Call it.    
    CALL funk(x, y)        
    externo = y        
    END FUNCTION externo
```

Comment: So what is your question? I can't find any question in your post. What kind of problem do you have with your code?

Comment: Your title mentions _C_, your question mentions _C/C++_ and you've tagged it as _C++_. You need to pick one.

Comment: Sentence 1 says, "I would like to share..."

Comment: If I see this correctly, you try to run the c++ code, then call the the fortran function with a function pointer as parameter and then call a callback functionin c++ from Fortran  before return a result back to c++, right? What's the problem/error here exactly?

Comment: I am just sharing...